# VirtualWebappLoader or similar for WebLogic to add directories to war's classpath?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

How can I make an external directory (where additional jars will be deployed) available on the classpath of a war deployed to WebLogic?

I am familiar with how to do this on Tomcat by defining a `Loader` element in the context.xml and including a `virtualClasspath` attribute which specifies `Additional repositories to search for resources`.

Is there a similar feature in WebLogic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes weblogic has the option to do this as well with `virtual-directory-mapping` inside weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">
  <virtual-directory-mapping>
    <local-path>C:\my\images</local-path>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>dir/*</url-pattern>
  </virtual-directory-mapping>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

See the [Oracle docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WBAPP/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP619)

Other options to use jars outside of a war include installing the jar as a [shared library](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/libraries.htm#WLPRG325) or simply including the jar files inside of your `<domain>/lib` folder to make them available to all applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file with name `.beabuild.txt` inside application's exploded directory and then map any directory or file to the application's directory.

#### Example usage

Let's assume we have Gradle multiproject build `ExampleProject`. Then `.beabuild.txt` could look like:

```
C\:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/asm/asm/1.5.3/63a2715c39c9e97f88fe371d4441a1b3493d74f9/asm-1.5.3.jar = APP-INF/lib/asm-1.5.3.jar
C\:/Users/User/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/asm/asm-all/2.2.3/9b79af5fc90f2dca349f16b771c21a43045f97ba/asm-all-2.2.3.jar = APP-INF/lib/asm-all-2.2.3.jar
C\:/Users/repos/ExampleProject/ui/src/main/webapp = ui.war
C\:/Users/repos/ExampleProject/ui/build/classes/main = ui.war/WEB-INF/classes
C\:/Users/repos/ExampleProject/ui/build/resources/main = ui.war/WEB-INF/classes
C\:/Users/repos/ExampleProject/common/build/classes/main = APP-INF/classes
C\:/Users/repos/ExampleProject/common/build/resources/main = APP-INF/classes
```

[Creating a Split Development Directory Environment](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/splitcreate.htm#WLPRG182) at docs.oracle.com