# Oracle Weblogic - How to work on UI without building the entire solution?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, server, weblogic

I'm a `UI developer` with very less knowledge in server side. My current work included `Oracle Weblogic` server, with `Java` coding language. 
The problem is, for each minor change that I make in `UI` file like js or html, I need to stop the server and rebuild the entire solution to see the change. This is taking a huge effort from a UI perspective.
Is there any way to work on UI files without building each time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to _WL_user directory (e.g. `Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\<your _domain_name>\servers\<server_name>\tmp\_WL_user\<application_name>`). In one of folders below (e.g. `<...>\war\WEB-INF\jsp`), you should find your UI files which you can modify. After reloading a page results should be visible in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *could* just connect a debugger to your server from your IDE so changes you make are pushed remotely, but it's not an elegant solution (and there are things it can't handle and you'll need to bounce the server anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Split Development Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41803071/2211754) in exploded folder. Then, all you need is to write one file `.beabuild.txt` and map virtual JS/CSS paths to your source folders.