# Running weblogic from intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, weblogic

I have weblogic setup to run from intellij. Part of the deployment includes a few war's that are from other sources inside my group but not compiled in the pre-deploy ant build. When I try to deploy them intellij squawks about it already existing. Which is ok. But, I was wondering if there was a way to simply a) tell intellij to overwrite/update these apps or b) run a pre-deploy task, say with WLST to deletes all of my apps so they new ones coming-in are just deployed fresh each time>

Comment: You can run some external task via Maven or Ant that would undeploy existing apps, it's not possible out of the box. IntelliJ IDEA deploys the apps from the specified artifact locations by instructing the app server to load apps from there instead of using the default deployment locations.

Comment: Ok, I can create a WLST script and tie it to an ant target. Thanks!

Comment: Using [Split Development Environment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41803071/2211754) you can avoid redeploy at all